# Variable not visible

Tags: apex, compile-error, global-variables

When I try to save the code (API version 43), I keep getting a compile error stating:

**Error: Compile Error: Variable is not visible: testClass.XYZ at line 5**

Here is the class:

```
global with sharing testclass{

public static final Integer XYZ {get;}
public static final Integer ABC {get;}
public static final Integer DEF {get;}

static {
        XYZ = 20;
         ABC = 20;
          DEF = 20;

    }     
rest of the class { }
}
```

I tried changing the variable to global etc..Any workaround for this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify a setter, you cannot set a variable's value. It is forever read-only, even to the class it is contained in. `final` is sufficient to make sure it cannot be modified later, but you'll need to allow the values to be set via a default setter:

```
global class testclass {
    public static final Integer XYZ {get; private set; }
    public static final Integer ABC {get; private set; }
    public static final Integer DEF {get; private set; }

    static {
        XYZ = 20;
        ABC = 20;
        DEF = 20;

    }
}
```

Note that final static variables can only be set during a static block (as you've done here) or inline assignments, and non-static variables marked final may only be initialized in a constructor or inline assignments.

Comment: Thanks. that did resolve it. Still Wondering how could the class get saved in the earlier versions without using the set..Any idea?

Comment: I figured that out that removing `get` works, but didn't realize that you actually need to have a `set` in place for constants. Everyday feels like the documentation keeps on missing some very useful information.

Comment: @Kalyan It may have been a bug or something in the compiler. Several years ago, they did a major revamp of the compiler to support new features (like the new switch statement). It's entirely possible that this was one of those bugs they got around to fixing. I don't know for sure, because I've never intentionally tried that before.

Comment: @JayantDas I personally use a different type of constant: `public static Integer XYZ { get { return 20; }}` this has the same final behavior as other constants, but reduces CPU time in large constant classes. In one case, I actually managed to shave off 1 second *per transaction* by converting a constants class to this format.

Comment: That’s great to know. I was **overthinking** around automatic properties for static members :)

Comment: Methods are final by default. Your code won't compile.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sure it does. I didn't specify final in the actual code.

Comment: I have 100% for certain gotten compile errors from `public static final Integer XYZ {get; private set; }`. Did they change that this release or?

Comment: @AdrianLarson automatic getters and setters are not methods. This has worked for a while. If you specify a method body, they are no longer automatic and will give you the error you're thinking of.